# Extracting a table by PHP cURL after login

Tags: php, curl

How can I get a table of content out by using PHP cURL? I have to enter name before getting into the page of having the table. I have written few code on how to get the page of having the table, but I doný know how can I extract that out and paste it on my site with the same formatting? (it contains Text and hyperlink)

```
<?php
function search($url,$data){
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => -1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "bot",
  ));

  if(curl_errno($curl)) {
    print_r(curl_error($curl));
    die();
  }

  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  return $result;
}

$data = "name=name&submit=submit";
$url = "www.extenal.com";
$test = search($url,$data);
echo $test;

$dom  = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($result);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsById('table');
return $nodes;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code to extract html, I have used DOMxpath, see in below link to learn how to use wildcard to get specific element from html response:

```
<?php
$htmlreponse = "<table><tr><td>test 1</td><td>test 2</td></tr></table>";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($htmlreponse);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//table') as $table){
    echo $table->C14N();
    //if you need only content then use this
    echo $table->textContent;
}
```

Here you can learn more about domxpath, you can apply different wilcard to get specific data as well :http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php